# Magento 2: Get Customer data before login with observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer

I want to check customer group around the login process

and want to add some custom code over there.

Anyone have any idea?

Please tell me.

Comment: Please explain  where your `some code over there`? .you cannot get customer data until customer set in  session,

Answer (score 3):

You can try creating a [plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for the method `loginById` of class `Magento\Customer\Model\Session`

or

you can try creating the [observer](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html) for the `customer_login` event.

Comment: Can I use before login event ?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any before login event, but you can try using customer_login event.

Comment: usefull list for the events in M2 and where each is dispatched
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html

Answer (score 2):

create module directory structure like the following:
[image]

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_CustomerLogin',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_CustomerLogin" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer instance="Namespace\CustomerLogin\Observer\Frontend\Customer\Login" name="namespace_customerlogin_observer_frontend_customer_login_customer_login"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer/Frontend/Customer/Login.php

```
<?php


namespace Namespace\CustomerLogin\Observer\Frontend\Customer;

class Login implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        //Here you can get your customer data by following
          echo $customerGroup=$this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();

    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    echo $customer->getName(); //Get customer name
    echo $customer->getGroupId(); //Get customer group and place your Logic here what you want to Do.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please follow the below code**

**1**.Create a **events.xml** file under "Namespace/Module/etc/frontend"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="custom_login_data" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\CustomerData" shared="false" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**2**.Create a observer(**CustomerData.php**) under "Namespace/Module/Observer"

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerData implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;
    protected $groupRepository;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository)
    {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $data = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $groupName = $this->getGroupName($data->getGroupId());//will return you the Group Name
        /*you can add here your custom code */
        return $this;
    }

    public function getGroupName($groupId){
        $group = $this->groupRepository->getById($groupId);
        echo $group->getCode();
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you!