# Log in with custom customer data

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom, login

I've added a customer custom data (code_client) to the customer info and I want the user to be able to login with both the email addresses and that code_client.

Is it possible to log in to my store without using only an email address?

Find some hint on the stack  : [Magento 2: Get Customer data before login with observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244062/magento-2-get-customer-data-before-login-with-observer)

But there's no mention of the password and how to check it.

Comment: Check this, https://github.com/diglin/Diglin_Username2 , https://github.com/semaio/Magento2-AdvancedLogin

Comment: I'm currently trying AdvancedLogin, thanks, I'll let you know I this is working.

Comment: @MorganTartreau I can help you, let me know a few things first, did you create custom customer attribute?

Comment: Yes I did, all my user have this attribute. I've configured the plugin in admin panel, I'm trying to display the right login form (i'm showing the default login form as I'm using a custom theme)

Comment: You need to rewrite the login action or the authetnticate method and change logic there.

Comment: @MorganTartreau checkout the answer

Comment: The Advance Plugin is working well, just need to change the customer_form_login template if you use custom theme !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `code_client` is your custom attribute and you already store your custom attribute during customer registration.

First, please check that your `code_client` is storing value or not, you can find it on `customer_entity_<type of your code_client>` table, for example, if `code_client` is varchar you can find value in 'customer_entity_varchar' where `code_client's` attribute_id is mentioned.

if its storing unique value for every customer you can now focus on login with that attribute.

Override login.phtml

Path:

> Magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml

change `type=email`to`type=email` & remove data-validate for email.

```
  <input name="login[username]" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getUsername()) ?>" <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()) : ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?> id="email" type="text" class="input-text" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}' data-validate="{required:true}">
```

In your routes.xml

```
<route id="username" frontName="username">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Customer" />
</route>
```

Create etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Index\LoginPost" />
</config>
```

In your Controller: LoginPost.php

Please add in to your __construct  (\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer)

```
  public function execute()
{
    if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
            try {
                if (strpos($login['username'], '@') === false){
                   $getCustomer = $this->customer->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('code_client', $login['username'])
                        ->getFirstItem();
                    if($login['username'] == $getCustomer->getUsername()){
                        $login['username'] = $getCustomer->getEmail();
                    }
                }
                //rest of the code
```

Let me know if need any help!!

Comment: Not tested, but I think I would recommand this method if you want to make a custom plugin. The AdvancePlugin (github.com/semaio/Magento2-AdvancedLogin) works perfectly. Thanks anyway !